# Android:If statement executing once

Tags: java, android, if-statement

So im developing an app and i have a problem.So im made a list then i parse data from that activity to an adapter activity that takes that data.

And that works fine.But there is a litle problem.There is 100 items and when you enter them its working good.And i wanted to put arrows that would navigate trough that without exiting.But the if just works once.I thing that the if is used just once.I tried to resfresh teh activity but it gets on the activity that the data was parsed.Here is the code so you could have a better look:

```
public class NutritionAdapter extends Activity {
    TextView Title;
    String TitleBar;
    TextView Text;
    Button right;
    Button left;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setContentView(R.layout.nutrition_adapter_layout);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_nutirtion_tips_text_view);
        Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tip_text_text_view);
        right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right_button);
        left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left_button);

        Title.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("TitleNut") + "");

        TitleBar = Title.getText().toString();

        if (TitleBar.equals("Tip 1")) {
            Text.setText(getText(R.string.tip_1) + "");

        } else if (TitleBar.equals("Tip 2")) {
            Text.setText(getText(R.string.tip_2) + "");

        } else if (TitleBar.equals("Tip 3")) {
            Text.setText(getText(R.string.tip_3) + "");

        } else if (TitleBar.equals("Tip 4")) {
            Text.setText(getText(R.string.tip_4) + "");

        } else if (TitleBar.equals("Tip 5")) {
            Text.setText(getText(R.string.tip_5) + "");
        } else if (TitleBar.equals("Tip 6")) {
            Text.setText(getText(R.string.tip_6) + "");

        } .........
                 else if (TitleBar.equals("Tip 100")) {
            Text.setText(getText(R.string.tip_100) + "");

        }

        right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (TitleBar.equals("Tip 1")) {
                    Title.setText("Tip 2");
                    Text.setText(getText(R.string.tip_2) + "");

                } else if (TitleBar.equals("Tip 2")) {
                    Title.setText("Tip 3");
                    Text.setText(getText(R.string.tip_3) + "");

                } else if (TitleBar.equals("Tip 3")) {
                    Title.setText("Tip 4");
                    Text.setText(getText(R.string.tip_4) + "");
                                   .........................

                }

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting `onCreate` to be called as you navigate? [See the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), it's called when the app is launched or when it's re-shown after being killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity is created, Layout is created, views are created and will have same text as defined at the beginning. This will happen every time. Nothing changes in between. Obviously, only one `if` condition will match.

Instead of placing conditional logic in `onCreate()`, place it in an event handler ( like :`OnClickListener`) to run `if` checks after some thing has changed, like a user input or other event.